# Only MySQL in Zabbix frontend configuration

Tags: debian, postgresql, zabbix

I upgraded my Debian 8 to 9, with zabbix-server installed. After upgrade I reinstalled zabbix-frontend-php. I'm trying to reconfigure frontend and in step "Configure DB connection" there is only MySQL as a database type. How can I connect it to Postgresql?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your PHP doesn't support PostgreSQL. Try to install package `php-pgsql` (`php5-pgsql`, ...) and then restart your web server.

Comment: php-pgsql is already installed and there is no php-mysql package installed

Answer (score 2):

As Jan Garaj said you need to install `php-pgsql`. But you also want to uncomment

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

in `/etc/php/php.ini` (or `locate php.ini`). If you're using `nginx` and `php-fpm`, don't forget to restart both.

Comment: Restarting php-fpm did it for me